# Warning in yard with @param tag

Tags: ruby, documentation, yard

I was trying to document some Ruby code using `yard`and even though I am doing exactly what is described [here](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#param) or [here](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#Reference_Tags)

```
# @param [Integer] the number of trials (>= 0)
# @param [Float] success probability in each trial
def initialize(n, p)
  # initialize...
end
```

I still get this strange error though

```
@param tag has unknown parameter name: the
@param tag has unknown parameter name: success
```

and then the generated html looks wierd. I am calling `yard` this:

```
$ yard doc -m markdown
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

doc says @param tag has format

```
@param [Type] name description
```

and your lines do not include param names (n and p respectively)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hadn't noticed it. it's not very clear from looking at the examples at the [getting started document](http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#Reference_Tags)

Comment: indeed it's very easy to miss that param name is required in there. glad i could help you, cheers!

Comment: As of Yard 0.8.7.3, the syntax is `@param name [Types] description`.

Comment: @karatedog Yes, but the old one still seems to work.